# Using query to copy rows where one column contains a specific substring

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following Google Spreadsheet:

```
A      B
foo_1  10
foo_2  20
bar_1  30
bar_2  40
```

I would like to create new columns selecting out rows that contain `foo` within cells in column A, i.e.:

```
A      B    C       D
foo_1  10   foo_1   10
foo_2  20   foo_2   20
bar_1  30
bar_2  40
```

Is there a way to achieve that using `=query`, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Found out myself:
  `=query(A1:A10, "select * where A contains 'foo'")`